# Outlook FROM field does NOT match Contacts Address Book

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server

Platform: Outlook 2013 as my email client.

Problem: I have contacts stored in Contacts Address Book, not the GAL;

When an email is received from someone, what I see in the FROM field is not equivalent to what is located in MY Contacts Address Book in Outlook.

I see, what I assume, is the way the user set up their account in their respective email service providers.

As an example, I have "Good Friend ", but when I receive an email from this person, it displays, e.g. "John Smith ".

How can I get Outlook "know" to display what my contacts' info in MY contacts address?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, yes, sorry, I should have been more thorough. I would like to do this in C# and bounce all of the received emails against the Contacts Address book and link them via the email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the sender email address (`MailItem.SenderEmailAddress`), open the Contacts folder `(Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolerContacts)`), search for a matching contact using `MAPIFolder.Items.Find` with a query like `"([Email1Address] = 'user@domain.demo') or ([Emai21Address] = 'user@domain.demo') or ([Email3Address] = 'user@domain.demo')"` .

Once you have ContactItem object, read its FileAs property and set the PR_SENDER_NAME and PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME properties on the original message using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty. The DASL names of the properties are

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1A001F"
```

and

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001F"
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully, thanks! My only caveat is that I can do this programmatically via a c# program, but I don't know how I can manipulate the Outlook UI to show these properties, e.g. in the default list view of emails, append names to whatever is displayed in the FROM column?

Comment: What do you want to display in that column? The view can only display a property set on a message. You can modify the view to display your property and stamp each message with your special property that the view will show.

Comment: It seems that due to different email providers and/or how users registered their email accounts, I have some emails displayed either (1) just their names or (2) just their email addresses. I need both and I know that ALL of these contacts are in my Contacts Address Book so I was thinking I can just make a service call to it and find that pertinent account and concatenate the both. Does this help? Thank you for your help.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. Outlook extracts the sender name/address from the MIME headers of the incoming message - you can see that data in the PR_TRANSPORT_MESAGE_HEADERS property (take a look at the item with OutlookSpy). You are welcome to change name/address properties programmatically. Outlook does not do that out of the box.

Comment: I understand that Outlook does not offer that out of the box and that is why I am going down thew programmatic path. Programmatically, I am able to get the properties that the requirements ask for and I owe it to your advice, BUT what I am now seeking is, I don't know how to integrate it (my code) into Outlook, e.g. do I crate an Outlook 2013 Add-in and if so, what even handler(s) do I need to include my code so when the emails are viewed via the main list view, my property is displayed? That's what I can't seem to find. Thanks!

Comment: You need to decide which programming language you want to use. C# along with VSTO would probably be the easiest. You will need to trap the Application.NewMailEx event, open the new message by the entry id using Namespace.GetItemfromId, then run your code against it.